# What does the root of a number really mean?

Tags: radicals

Now we know that:

- A number raised to n : `xⁿ = x * x * x * x ...n`
- A number raised to -n : `x⁻ⁿ = 1/x * x * x * x ...n`

But what would a root of a number (i.e. `x¹/ⁿ`) be?

What would *"a number raised to 1/n"* be?

Or a better way to interpret the question : *How would you represent a number raised to 1/n?*

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/132703/what-does-2x-really-mean-when-x-is-not-an-integer/133238

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike for integers, where $x^n$ is the result of some manipulation, $x^{1/n}$ is *defined as* the solution of an equation. Namely, for positive $x$, we define $y := x^{1/n}$ as the unique positive solution of the equation $y^n = x$. $x^{1/n}$ is then a convenient abuse of notation because it is compatible with the power law that we are used to:
$$(x^a)^b = x^{ab}.$$
Consequently, we can then *define* $x^{m/n}$ as $(x^m)^{1/n}$ (or $(x^{1/n})^m$, which conveniently results in the same) for $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$. It is important here that you don't think of it as some sort of fractional multiplication of $x$ with itself, but rather as a convenient definition that happens to coincide with the usual powers for integers.

A similar concept would be something like $\log_{10}(2)$. It is *defined* as the unique solution of $10^x = 2$ and, a priori, not obtained by some sort of manipulation.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so what I've understood,

If you have a number `x` and it is raised to `1/n`,
then that number can be represented as `yⁿ = x`, where `y ∈ R`.

Which can be also written as log<sub>y</sub>(x) = n, where `y` is *base* and `x` is the *number* and `n` is just *the number of times `y` must be multiplied by itself*.

So if you want to find any number raised to `1/n`, you have to find the *base* of the logarithm.

Now after scouring the web I have found a [formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/31341/1091359) to find the *base* of a logarithm. Even so, the formula requires the use of a calculator which you might as well use that calculator to find the root of that number.

Now I know that the above definition is really generalized, but it's a good start to understand roots. *I guess?*

Now **Klaus** has posted an in-depth answer to this and **Dan** has posted a frankly *encyclopedic* [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/132703/what-does-2x-really-mean-when-x-is-not-an-integer/133238). It goes really deep into this topic.

Huge thanks to **Klaus** and **Dan**.

Comment: Correct, but your answer does not add anything new to the one already given or to Dan's comment, so it is not clear what its purpose is.

Comment: @AlexM. Its not supposed to add anything, its just simplifying. Its a *simple* answer. For that reason I have not marked as *the best* one.